# Proof of reflected and refracted waves being in the same plane as that of the incident wave and its projection on a planar interface

Tags: waves, scattering, reflection, refraction, boundary-conditions

Please give a proof of reflected and refracted waves being in the same plane as that of the incident wave and its projection on an ideal planar interface between two linear, homogeneous, isotropic, elastic solids (preferably without resorting to variation/extrema principles, but rather just from continuity of displacement and continuity of traction).

I know (using Cartesian coordinates) if we set the $x$ and $y$ unit vectors parallel to the normal vectors of the plane of incidence and the interface respectively, and place the $x=0$ and $y=0$ coordinates respectively, then we have coplanarity of the reflected and transmitted waves with the incident wave from linear independence of the exponential functions. I'm hesitant to assume to invariance of the origin in this situation.  If this suffices for a proof (via arbitrariness of the origin with respect to the aforementioned two planes), please give or direct me to the proof of invariance of the origin that this situation is a (not necessarily strict) subset of.

Comment: @Qmechanic I am pretty new here. Can you please tell me why you changed my tags?  From my naive perspective, you removed two tags that gave a more complete description of the question and replaced them with two that redundantly fall under scattering and narrowed my audience by a huge margin. (I was about to type "thank you."  You deleted that in my question.  So, I won't be putting that my questions anymore.  Does the same go for comments?)

Comment: Hi @beef42 : Welcome to Phys.SE. I cannot promise to answer all you questions because of time constraints. E.g. check out the [meta site](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/360/2451). Concerning tags, be aware that that they serve not just for humans but also robots, which don't know what is redundant or even similar. Anyway, feel free to change your post in ways that you think would improve it.